# Extra Incorrect KVO Insertion Called on NSOrderedSet When Saving Child NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: cocoa, core-data, key-value-observing

I have an `NSManagedObject` with an `NSOrderedSet` to-many relationship named `subpointConnections_`. I am observing changes to this set using the following:

```
addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(subpointConnections_), options: [], context: &subpointsOC)
```

This can be called only once in the initialisation of a lazy property on the `NSManagedObject`.

Any new relations are added in a child `NSManagedObjectContext`, and then saved down to my main context.

When I set the relationship, I use the following code, only setting the 'many' side of the relationship from the 'one':

```
superpoint.insertIntoSubpointConnections_(self, at: index)
```

`insertIntoSubpointConnections_` is an autogenerated accessor.

In the child `NSManagedObjectContext` I see a single correct call to `observeValue(forKeyPath...`, that gives me the correct insertion index on `subpointConnections_`, when the above insertion code is called.

However, when I save to the parent `NSManagedObjectContext` I am seeing two calls to `observeValue(forKeyPath...` on the same object. The first call is for an insertion at the end of the `NSOrderedSet`. The second call is for an insertion at the correct position.

When evaluating the `NSOrderedSet` in each observation call, the new object is indeed at the position described - it is on the end of the set on the first call, and then moved to the correct position on the second call. However, I get no call to say that it was removed from the end position.

I am not sure if I have set something up incorrectly here. The many objects in my one-many relationship will be unique, so I could write the code to work around this, but that feels wrong.

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Weirdly, the first change dictionary passed to `observeValue(forKeyPath...` contains an `NSIndexSet`, the second contains an `NSMutableIndexSet`.

**EDIT**

I have replicated this issue in a simple project here: https://github.com/GilesHammond/KVO-Core-Data-Extra/

Run in debug and select "ADD CHILD" multiple times from the app Main Menu. Observe the debug output showing the extra erroneous observation on the main NSManagedObjectContext.

Comment: Even if I work around this, I can't ignore the initial incorrect notification, and the insert then move action will bubble all the way up to my interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Apple Support and have submitted this issue as a bug as suggested, as the given notifications are not atomic.

I had to take a different approach. I now update my NSManageObject when the NSManagedObjectContextDidSave notification is posted.